# How can I send back the captured image taken from second activity back to the main activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-image

This is my code from the main activity class named `Account` class wherein when I press the add entry button it will navigate to the next activity which is the `AddEntry` class

```
    //ADD ENTRY BUTTON
    accountBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Account.this, AddEntry.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_CODE_ADD);
        }
    });
```

After it goes to the second activity which is the `AddEntry` class, a picture would be captured using the user's camera when the ImageView named entryPhoto is clicked

```
    entryPhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent takePhoto = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            File tempImage = null;
            try {
                tempImage = createImage();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (tempImage != null){
                Uri uriImage = FileProvider.getUriForFile(c,"com.example.login.fileprovider",
                        tempImage);
                mCurrentPhotoUri = uriImage;
                takePhoto.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,uriImage);

                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(c, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(AddEntry.this,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                            REQ_CODE_CAMERA);

                }
                else {
                    startActivityForResult(takePhoto,REQ_CODE_TAKE_PHOTO);
                }

            }
        }
    });
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == REQ_CODE_TAKE_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        entryPhoto.setImageURI(mCurrentPhotoUri);
    }
```

Here is the code where I put all the the information inputted by user then send it back to the main activity. In the addPhoto is where I am supposed to put the image to be passed. I only tried passing an image from my drawable because I really don't know how to pass the image captured.

```
    Intent data = new Intent();
                data.putExtra("addPhoto",R.drawable.anonymous);
                data.putExtra("addName", entryName.getText().toString());
                data.putExtra("addRemark", entryRemark.getText().toString());
                data.putExtra("addBirthday", entryBirthday.getText().toString());
                data.putExtra("addAddress", entryAddress.getText().toString());
                data.putExtra("addGender", selectedGender);
                data.putExtra("addContactNo", entryContactNo.getText().toString());
                data.putExtra("addHobbies", entryHobbies.getText().toString());
                data.putExtra("addOtherInfo", entryOtherInfo.getText().toString());
                setResult(RESULT_OK,data);
                finish();
```

And this is the code in the onActivityResult in the main activity

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); //ONACTRESULT OF ADD ENTRY
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_ADD && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        int addPhoto = data.getIntExtra("addPhoto",1);
        String addName = data.getStringExtra("addName");
        String addRemark = data.getStringExtra("addRemark");
        String addBirthday = data.getStringExtra("addBirthday");
        String addAddress = data.getStringExtra("addAddress");
        String addContactNo = data.getStringExtra("addContactNo");
        String addGender = data.getStringExtra("addGender");
        String addHobbies = data.getStringExtra("addHobbies");
        String addOtherInfo = data.getStringExtra("addOtherInfo");

        entryList.add(0,new Entry(addPhoto,addName,addRemark,addBirthday,addGender,addAddress,addContactNo,addHobbies,addOtherInfo));
        myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Please I hope you will help me. I am still a beginner but I really want to be good at programming. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can pass the `Uri` directly in bundle of `Intent` as it extends `Parcelable` which means it can retrieved as is

**Adding**

```
data.putExtra("addPhoto", mCurrentPhotoUri);
```

**Retrieving**

```
Uri photoUri = getIntent().getParcelableExtra<Uri>("addPhoto");
```

Comment: Can you also tell me how will I be able to add that to my arraylist?
entryList.add(0,new Entry(addPhoto,addName,addRemark,addBirthday,addGender,addAddress,addContactNo,addHobbies,addOtherInfo));
given that addPhoto is an integer